# Laravel unique validation rule with except not working

Tags: laravel

Laravel unique validation rule with except column not working on update, what's wrong in my code ?

```
public function update(Request $request, Article $article)
{
    abort_if($article->user_id !== $request->user()->id, 403);

    $article = $request->user()->articles()->update($request->validate([
        'title' => [
            'required',
            Rule::unique('articles', 'title')->ignore($article->id)
        ],
        'content'=>'required|min:90',
    ]));

    return redirect('articles/'.$article->id)->withSuccess('Article saved.');
}
```

> Error : The title has already been taken.

Laravel version : `6.4.0`

Thanks for help

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the entire instance of article to validate like:

```
Rule::unique('articles')->ignore($article);
```

Because you are already saying what column to check.

https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/validation

Comment: tysm. ignore by id didnt work, this works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Remove title from

```
Rule::unique('articles', 'title')->ignore($article->id)
```

to

```php
...
$article = $request->user()->articles()->update($request->validate([
        'title' => [
            'required',
            Rule::unique('articles')->ignore($article->id)
        ],
        'content'=>'required|min:90',
    ]));
...
```

Hope this helps

more info, check [rule-unique](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/validation#rule-unique)

Comment: It seems like I had duplicate titles in the database. I don't know why but I deleted all the duplicates in the database and now it works. Rule::unique('articles')->ignore($article->id) and Rule::unique('articles')->ignore($article) and Rule::unique('articles', 'title')->ignore($article->id) are all working now.

Answer (score 1):

If you run the update on `$request->user()->articles()` you will update all of the user's articles. If the user only has 1 article then it should work just fine, however if there are more then this will result in data being overwritten.

Instead do:

```php
$article->update($request->validate([
    'title' => [
        'required',
        Rule::unique('articles', 'title')->ignore($article->id)
     ],
    'content'=>'required|min:90',
]));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `softDelete` and you deleted an object that has the same `title`, don't forget to check if the `deleted_at` column is `null`.

```php
    $request->validate([
        'title' => [
            'required',
            Rule::unique('articles', 'title')
                ->ignore($article->id)
                ->whereNull('deleted_at')
        ],
        'content'=>'required|min:90',
    ])
```